# handling single and double quotes while fetching and printing in the page

Tags: php

sorry ma question went wrong a bit the alis has value like alias ="Sri Kumaran Children's Home - CBSENothing is as pure and divine as knowledge." but as the url i have given . when i hover over the link it just shows alias=Sri Kumaran Children . how to solve this problem

```
 $myresult .= "<a href='Schools/{$alias}'><img src='/school/schoolpicdisplay.php?p1={$brand}&p2={$model}' width=\"50\" height=\"80\"></img></a>";
```

Comment: why are you storing the field name as part of the field value? Just store ' Sri Kumaran Children's Home' in the model field and build the GET string in PHP.

Comment: Your width and height attributes' values can be surrounded by single-quotes as well, to make it more consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know there will be a single quote, why don't you use double quotes in the first place?

```
"...<img src=\"/school/schoolpicdisplay.php?p1={$brand}&p2={$model}\"..."
```

However, since your `$model` is going to be in a parameter string, you should [`rawurlencode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) it.

```
$encoded_model = rawurlencode($model);
$encoded_alias = rawurlencode($alias);
$myresult .= "<a href='Schools/{$encoded_alias}'>...p1={$encoded_brand}&p2={$encoded_model}...";
```

Comment: sorry ma question went wrong a bit 
the alis has value like alias ="Sri Kumaran Children's Home - CBSENothing is as pure and divine as knowledge." but as the url i have given . when i hover over the link it just shows alias=Sri Kumaran Children . how to solve this problem

Comment: @pradeep: (1) edit your question if it went wrong. (2) see update.

Comment: okie the rawurlencode worked . is there no other way to tackle this problem ?

Comment: @pradeep: There are tons of other escaping functions but `urlencode` or `rawurlencode` are the most suitable in your case.

Comment: okie. so there is no problem with my php statement. i tot of playing with the quotes in the statement to handle the problem .

Comment: is it mandatory to rawurldecode the encoded string . if its not done.wht problems might occour?

Comment: @pradeep: It's not mandatory. But if your `$model` can be `blah&p1=bar` then an incorrect page will be shown.

Comment: hii..i got a similar problem related to this only .
i solved tht quotes problem with the rawurlencode . but i am facing another problem. like
the alias has value like $alias = "Sony DSC-TX1/H"
when i am making it an url like 


   1. <a href="<?php echo ucfirst($value).'/'.rawurlencode($row1['alias']); ?>"><?php echo $row1['property1']; echo " ";echo $row1['property2'] ?></a>

its leading to a page not found like
The requested URL /Cameras/SonyDSC-TX1/H was not found on this server.
the / is making a prob .will the rawurlencode take care of slash?

http://xyz.com/Cameras/SonyDSC-TX1%2FH

Comment: @pradeep: Yes it will. If that's not a query component you can use `htmlentities` instead.

Comment: its a url component only! but its not handling it . its taking it  like a path  rather than a single variable!

Comment: any solutiion to this problem where in the variable with '/' in url is giving problem!